# wiredep angular-translate-loader-partial is not injected

Tags: angularjs, translate, wiredep

I want to split up my json translate files by using the angular-translate-loader-partial plugin

```
bower install angular-translate-loader-partial
```

Does not wiredep the .js file in my index.html (even with --save-dev)
So I implemented it manually

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/swiper/dist/idangerous.swiper.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/shareform.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

During liveview it does work, but if I do "grunt build" it doesn't work anymore
Probably it isn't part of the build

Comment: is it listed in your bower.json file?

Comment: yes it is under devDependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it under `dependencies` in your bower.json. For future reference use the `--save` flag for dependencies and `--save-dev` for devDependencies.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. No idea what the differences are.

Comment: @moasking The difference is, when you are developing a bower module and you type bower install, it will install all dependencies and devDependencies. However, if you install a bower module only the dependencies are installed. So dependencies are modules you need in production and devDependencies are modules you need in development (e.g. chai)